# Framework code: Fail silently or throw exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, oop, frameworks

Say I have a method that exists in a library/framework, I want to know if the methods should throw exceptions or fail silently; for example:

```
void PerformAction(Item item)
{
    // throws NullReferenceException if item is null
    item.DoThis();
}

void PerformAction(Item item)
{
    //fails silently
    if(item != null)
    {
        item.DoThis();
    }
}
```

Which solution is better - or is this a bit of a subjective question?

Comment: This would be highly subjective, though I believe that the majority of voices will say you should mostly `throw`. At least for debugging purposes. If the framework has a logging mechanism, you should log the failed task if you're not willing to throw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by others, this may be subjective, and may also dependent on context and situation. As a general rule though, I would think that throwing is by far the preferable option.

---

**I like this simple analogy; naïve as it may be, it makes a clear and valid point:**

*Boss:* Hey Joe, could you do me a favor and run down to accounting and deliver these important documents there for me? 
*Joe:* Sure, no problem.

*Joe goes down to Accounting, but finds the door locked, and everybody out to lunch*

**Possible follow-up #1:**

*Joe returns to his boss:* Sorry, the office was closed. I can try again later if you want me to, or perhaps you have some other option for getting the documents delivered?

**Possible follow-up #2:**

*Joe realises he can't complete the task, so he just drops the documents in a garbage collect.. um.. trash container, and calls it a day.*

Which option would you prefer if you were the boss?

Answer (score 3):

This is "really" a subjective question and depends on the case.

For example, if this api provides some operations on a DB, and whenever api user wants to create a record, ignoring silently will be a headache.

On the otherhand, if this operation is only optional, ignoring will cause no harm. For instance, api developer may want to save the number of operations performed using this api by using a web service. In this case, you may fail silently if service is not available since this is not the purpose of the api.

Also, another option exists; you may simply provide a different type of exception to provide data about optional exceptions. And you can allow users to enable or disable this option via configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should throw an exception. 
If you follow the [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)(POLA), the `PerformAction` should DO an action. So if the item is `null`, you cannot do the action, and you would expect feedback.

But then as stated, this is highly subjective.